# SelectionSort in Grokking Algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, syntax

I am struggling with a piece of **for loop in range()** in Grokking Algorithm book SelectionSort

```
def findthesmallest(arr):
    # suppose that the left list is sorted
    min = arr[0]
    min_index = 0

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < min:
            min = arr[i]
            min_index = i

    return min_index

def selectionsort(arr):
    new_arr = []
    # For each i+= 1, n-=1 
    for i in range (len(arr)):
        min_index = findthesmallest(arr)
        # Add item to new_arr and update the arr
        new_arr.append(arr.pop(min_index))

    return new_arr

print (selectionsort([5, 3, 4, 8, 10]))
```

- So in the second **selectionsort()** for_loop, every time we finish iteration,  len(arr) - 1
- while i increases each iteration, range(len(arr)) decreases.
- when I try to inspect each (i, len(arr)) of each iteration I get:
  (0,5), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)
- How could i = 4 in range(1) be possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the documentation about `for`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) you will see that

> The expression list is evaluated once

That means `range(len(arr))` will be evaluated once before the first iteration, and then never again. That means changes you make to `arr` will not be noticed by future iterations of the loop.

You need some other way to iterate over `arr`, perhaps a `while` loop. Or add a check to make sure that `i` is not out of bounds.

Comment: Thx for the answer. While_loop definitely works for me. I still try to visualize what function does i do here. Does it simply loop through original and updated [arr] while keeping track the number of loops?